# two tables query, strange multiplication in the result

Tags: php, mysql

Hi and thanks in advance for your answer/s.
I have two tables, tracks(info on music **tracks**, title, lenght, cd_id..etc) and **purchd_items**(purchased tracks, cd_id, user_id..etc). I have this query:

function blue($id)

```
{
    $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT tracks.id, tracks.track_id, tracks.cd_id, tracks.title, tracks.lenght, tracks.price, tracks.file, tracks.preview, tracks.hash, purchd_items.cd_id, purchd_items.name FROM tracks LEFT JOIN purchd_items ON tracks.cd_id = purchd_items.cd_id WHERE purchd_items.user_id = $user_id AND tracks.cd_id = $id GROUP BY tracks.title, purchd_items.name ORDER BY tracks.track_id");
    return $query->result();
```

}

What I am trying to do check two tables for match and display all the info from tracks table as well as matching items from **purchd_items** table that will replace the entries from **tracks** table. If the user has already bought any tracks I want to display the download link instead of usual buy track link.Kind of like itunes, I guess.

I was sort of able to get this working using the query above but the number of items in the returned array was multiplied by the number of entries in the **purchd_items** table and I couldn't get rid of the duplicates.

Hope I am making sense here! Thank you!

Comment: can you post your tables structure? and some record? Btw what is your query result?

Comment: @dArc

table tracks
id track_id cd_id title lenght price file preview hash
-- -------- ----- ----- ------ ----- ---- ------- ----
1  1        2     trck1 5.00   0.99  xx   xxxx    xxxx
2  2        2     trck2 3.22   0.99  xx   xxxx    xxxx

table purchd_items
id user_id cd_id order_number name  purchased_file buyers_name
-- ------- ----- ------------ ----  -------------- -----------
1  1       2     xxxxx2       trck1 xxxx           xxxxxxx
2  1       2     xxxxx4       trck2 xxxxx          xxxx

[link](http://imgur.com/YzbYHHC)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

SELECT tracks.id, tracks.track_id, tracks.cd_id, tracks.title, tracks.lenght, tracks.price, tracks.file, tracks.preview, tracks.hash, purchd_items.cd_id, purchd_items.name FROM tracks LEFT JOIN purchd_items ON tracks.cd_id = purchd_items.cd_id AND purchd_items.name = tracks.title AND purchd_items.user_id = $user_id WHERE tracks.cd_id = $id ORDER BY tracks.id